# Post-hyphenation of split compound words

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, suspended-hyphen

Assuming that these two words

> off-topic
>
> on-topic

*must* be hyphenated, which of the punctuations in the following sentences is correct? (crucial part emphasized)

> Regardless of whether it is an **off or on-topic** example, it is a brilliant consideration in the definition of this proposal.
>
> Regardless of whether it is an **off- or on-topic** example, it is a brilliant consideration in the definition of this proposal.

I know you can get around this with a verbose constuction like *off-topic or on-topic*, or by not hyphenating either and treating *off* and *on* and *topic* as separate words, but neither suggestion really does anything to answer my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The standard way to deal with this in English is your second example, "off- or on-topic".  Another example of where the hyphen would be preserved for both forms of the hyphenated word might be *pre-* and *post-*, e.g.

> The pre- and post-match responses of the soccer fans were markedly different.

Comment: But, pray, why? What is the source of "the standard way"?

Comment: @Kris No idea whether it would help you but it's also the standard way in German and I could provide you a source for that.

Comment: @Kris Maybe the sources mentioned at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Suspended_hyphens could be helpful.