# Is the first hyphen in "Anti- and pro-American", "bi- and tri-monthy", "country- and state-specific" correct?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, suspended-hyphen

Those prefixes "Anti", "bi" etc would look odd as separate words, but then, even complete words like "country" or "state" ending with a dangling hyphen look odd. So what is the correct rule for this? Should I play safe and use it like "Anti-American and pro-American"? Please suggest the correct way to do it. Wikipedia article on English hyphens was of little help over this.

Comment: @tchrist http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27707/post-hyphenation-of-split-compound-words#comment367219_27708

Comment: Perhaps, can be merged with the earlier Q. cited by @tchrist.

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate question, though I find Kris' answer here superior to the accepted answer there.

Comment: @JonHanna Reading Kris's answer, I am glad I didn't delete my question. Anyways, tchrist's link was helpful

Answer (score 4):

- **Anti-** and pro-American
- **bi-** and tri-monthly
- **country-** and state-specific

"Ending with a dangling hyphen" need not look odd, it serves an important purpose, of signaling a **shared** prefix.

*Country and state specific* could be *country-and-state specific* or *country-specific and state-specific* or *country and state-specific* (the last instance, when the suffix applies only to the second and not shared.)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks!The "country-and-state specific" part is completely new to me, especially because there is no hyphen before specific. Also, I had the impression that the last instance ("country and state-specific") is wrong. I stand corrected. But I would really appreciate if you can explain briefly why it is correct. Can you give some more examples of the same so that I can understand the underlying rule behind it? Irrespective, your present answer nails it!!

Answer (score -2):

You can skip the first hyphen because the second one does the work:

Anti and Pro-American

Bi and Tri-Monthly

Country and State-Specific 
(Although I'm not really sure why this needs a hyphen at all...)