# full- or part-time day care

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

When abbreviating "full-time and part-time day care" to "full and part-time day care" should the word 'full' also be hyphenated even though the paired word is not stated - e.g. full- and part-time day care'?
Please advise
Thanks

Comment: I prefer it hyphenated. It is a bit uglier, but it avoids ambiguity.

Comment: _Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone._ -From the Help Center

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment and I'm not sure how to mark as duplicate, but this question appears to have been answered here;

[Post-hyphenation of split compound words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27707/post-hyphenation-of-split-compound-words)

The answer states you would keep the hyphen, so it would be "full- and part-time day care".

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You will be able to do both those things as soon as you have enough reputation. Have a look at the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers and reputation.